# How to 'zero' out rows & columns in an array

Tags: python, numpy, adjacency-matrix

I have a 2D array to represent a many-many mapping :

```
0   3   1   3
3   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
```

What is the quickest way to 'zero' out rows and column entries corresponding to a particular index in this array?

Comment: Do you really mean a many-many mapping, or is this a 1-1 mapping from pairs of names to numbers?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it's unclear what you are asking. Can you give a more complete example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
arr[i] = 0   # zeroes out row i
arr[:,i] = 0 # zeroes out column i
```

Comment: perhaps a useful addition: to zero out the whole matrix, use `a[:]=0`